# kendo ui: how to do default sorting, phone number formatting and replace the word null to none

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, user-interface, formatting, kendo-ui

in my code, i want to do the gird table with default sorting by last name ascending, phone number formatting with (xxx)-xxx-xxxx and replace the word null to none,for example some mobiel number is null, i want to display as none

```
{
                    field: "LName",
                    width: 100,
                    title: "Last Name",
                    defaultSorting: true

                }, {
                    field: "DateOfBirth",
                    width: 100,
                    title: "Date of Birth",
                    type: 'date',
                    template: '#= kendo.toString(DateOfBirth,"MM/dd/yyyy") #'

                }, {
                    field: "Email",
                    width: 230,
                    title: "Email"
                }, {
                    field: "MobileNumber",
                    width: 100,
                    title: "Mobile Number"


                },
```

any one done this before, or have idea plz help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting a default sort is done on the [data source](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#sort%20array%20%20objectdefault), and can be done like this:

```
sort: { field: "LName", dir: "asc" }
```

Formatting a phone number is a bit trickier, as there is no built in support for formatting them. You'll have to pull the number apart, then you can use the [format function](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#format) to format the number (assuming your number is formatted 1234567890):

```
function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    var piece1 = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3); //123
    var piece2 = phoneNumber.substring(3, 6); //456
    var piece3 = phoneNumber.substring(6); //7890

    //should return (123)456-7890
    return kendo.format("({0})-{1}-{2}", piece1, piece2, piece3);
}
```

To replace null with none use another template function.   This can also apply the phone number formatting:

```
template: '#= (MobileNumber) ? formatPhoneNumber(MobileNumber) : "none" #'
```

You'll need to make sure that your formatPhoneNumber function is scoped so that the kendo template can access it when binding.

Comment: ::: how do i make sure is scope?

Comment: The easiest way is to assign the formatPhoneNumber to the Window global object:  window.formatPhoneNumber = function(phoneNumber).  This isn't a best practice, however, it will get the job done.  Ideally you'd have a namespace in your application that you can assign functions like this to that is available globally.

Comment: if i initialize from html table can i set default sorting ??